# Unable to copy and apply a branch policy from one repo to another repo in azure devops

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-repos

Not able to copy the azure branch policy from one repo to another repo using the below PowerShell script

### **PowerShell script**

```
[CmdletBinding()]

param([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $AzureDevOpsPAT,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $OrganizationName,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $SourceProjectName,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $SourcerepositoryName,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $SourceBranch,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $TargetProjectName,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $TargetrepositoryName,[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $TargetBranch)

$ErrorActionPreference = ‘Stop’;

$User=“”;

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes((“{0}:{1}” -f $User,$AzureDevOpsPAT)));$header = @{Authorization=(“Basic {0}” -f $base64AuthInfo)};

Get Source repository

$sourceurl = ‘https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $SourceProjectName + ‘/_apis/git/repositories/’ + $SourcerepositoryName +’?api-version=5.1’$sourcerepository = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sourceurl -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header

$sourcepolicy = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $teamProjectName +‘/_apis/git/policy/configurations?repositoryId=’ + $sourcerepository.id + ‘&refName=refs/heads/’ + $SourceBranch + ‘&api-version=5.1-preview.1’

Get Target repository

$targeturl = ‘https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $TargetProjectName + ‘/_apis/git/repositories/’ + $TargetrepositoryName +’?api-version=5.1’$targetpository = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $targeturl -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $headerWrite-Output $targetpository

get policies

$Url = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $SourceProjectName + ‘/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=5.1’;$policies = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header

$policies.value | ConvertTo-Json

foreach($policy in $policies.value){if ($policy.type.id -eq ‘0517f88d-4ec5-4343-9d26-9930ebd53069’){continue; # skipping GitRepositorySettingsPolicyName}

# remove properties from policy so it can be applied to target branch
$props = $policy.PSObject.Properties
$props.remove('createdBy');
$props.remove('createdDate');
$props.remove('revision');
$props.remove('id');
$props.remove('url');

$policy._links.PSObject.Properties.Remove('self')

# set target branch

if (($null -ne $policy.settings.scope[0].refname))
{
    $policy.settings.scope[0].refName = 'refs/heads/' + $TargetBranch;
}
if (($null -ne $policy.settings.searchBranches))
{
    $policy.settings.searchBranches[0] = 'refs/heads/' + $TargetBranch;
}

# create policy in target branch

$body = $policy | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

$policyCreateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
$policyCreateResponse

}
```

### The error

**Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The update is rejected by**

**policy.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Policy.Server.PolicyChangeRejectedByPolicyException,**

**Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Policy.Server","typeKey":"PolicyChangeRejectedByPolicyException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}**

I am seeking a solution to copy a branch policy from one repository to another using either a script or an Azure pipeline. Can you please assist me with this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my testing, the reason you encounter the error "The update is rejected by policy" is that you are creating a branch policy on the source branch, which already has such a branch policy.  `$Url` is your source project.

```
$policyCreateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
```

I made some modifications based on your scripts and it works fine.

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = '{PAT}'
$OrganizationName = '{Org name}'
$SourceProjectName = '{Source Proj}'
$SourcerepositoryName = '{Source repo}'
$SourceBranch = '{Source branch}'
$SourceRefName = 'refs/heads/' + $SourceBranch
$TargetProjectName = '{Target Proj}'
$TargetrepositoryName = '{Target repo}'
$TargetBranch = '{Target branch}'
$TargetRefName = 'refs/heads/' + $TargetBranch

$ErrorActionPreference = ‘Stop’;

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)"))
$header = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }

#Get Source repository
$sourceurl = ‘https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $SourceProjectName + ‘/_apis/git/repositories/' + $SourcerepositoryName +'?api-version=5.1’
$sourcerepository = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $sourceurl -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
$sourcerepository | ConvertTo-Json
$sourcerepositoryid = $sourcerepository.id

#Get Target repository
$targeturl = ‘https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $TargetProjectName + ‘/_apis/git/repositories/’ + $TargetrepositoryName +’?api-version=5.1’
$targetrepository = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $targeturl -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header 
$targetrepository| ConvertTo-Json
$targetrepositoryid = $targetrepository.id

#Get policies
$URL1 = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $SourceProjectName + ‘/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=5.1’
$policies = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL1 -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header

#Target project URL
$URL2 = 'https://dev.azure.com/'+ $OrganizationName + ‘/’ + $TargetProjectName + ‘/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=5.1’

foreach($policy in $policies.value){

if ($policy.settings.scope.repositoryId -eq $sourcerepositoryid -and $policy.settings.scope.refName -eq $SourceRefName )
{

  if ($policy.type.id -in "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4916e5d171ab", "c6a1889d-b943-4856-b76f-9e46bb6b0df2", "40e92b44-2fe1-4dd6-b3d8-74a9c21d0c6e", "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd")
  {
    $policy.settings.scope[0].repositoryId = $targetrepositoryid
    $policy.settings.scope[0].refName = $TargetRefName
    $body = $policy | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10  

    Write-Host 'Create policy in the target branch'
    $policyCreateResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL2 -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
    $policyCreateResponse | ConvertTo-Json
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host 'There is no target policy type.'
  }

}

}
```

Based on the `policy.type.id` in my script `if ($policy.type.id -in "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4916e5d171ab", "c6a1889d-b943-4856-b76f-9e46bb6b0df2", "40e92b44-2fe1-4dd6-b3d8-74a9c21d0c6e", "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4906e5d171dd")`, it works for the following branch policies.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am ale to copy the branch policy from one repo  to another repo but still i am looking the solution to copy the policy with Build Validation and Automatically included reviewers options

Comment: Thanks, I am able to copy the branch policy with build reviewer from resource repo to target repo.